# How to resolve 'CrmServerLoginControl' not found in namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces, dynamics-crm

I've created a project using the [XRM tooling common login control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/dn689071.aspx) template in Visual Studio tergating the .Net 4.5 framework. But after the second time running the app the compiler tells me that the login control can't be found in the namespace:

> Error 15  The tag 'CrmServerLoginControl' does not exist in XML
>   namespace
>   'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl'.
>   Line 24 Position 10.

**Debugging steps:**

I've tried the following in order to resolve the namespace:

- Removing the assembly path from the namespace declaration
- Cleaning and rebuilding the solution
- Removing and re-adding the control from my xaml markup

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to debug this issue further?

**Code: (namespace and control declaration)**

```
xmlns:CrmLoginCtrl="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl;assembly=Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl"


<CrmLoginCtrl:CrmServerLoginControl Name="CrmLoginCtrl"
                                            Grid.Row="1"
                                            Margin="10,5"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                            ShowTitle="False" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but commenting here as it was missing the answer.

Check the References folder, within your Visual Studio project.
If various Dynamics 365 SDK references are showing warnings, take the following steps.

- Right Click the references Folder Select 'Manage Nuget Packages"
- Ensure that the SDK packages are displayed, If there are issues then
- You should have the option to "Restore" the connections, at the top right of the Dialog.
- Click Restore and once completed, close the
  Nuget manager dialog.

You should now be able to build the project without the error.

Note, All of this has a pre-requisite of having the Nuget packet manager installed, which is documented.

Hope this helps